# Why can one aliased C# Type not be accessed by another?

Tags: c#, .net, alias

good stuff

```
// ok to alias a List Type
using AliasStringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;

// and ok to alias a List of Lists like this
using AliasListOfStringList1 = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>;
```

bad stuff

```
// However **error** to alias another alias
using AliasListOfStringList2 = System.Collections.Generic.List<AliasStringList>;
```

Produces the compile error

> *The type or namespace name
>   'AliasStringList' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)*

Note: this is the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=VS.80).aspx) not the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just can't use an alias declared in a using inside another using.  For a set of usings like you have, you can assume that sibling using declarations don't exist.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(VS.71).aspx)

> The order in which *using-alias-directives* are written has no significance, and resolution of the *namespace-or-type-name* referenced by a *using-alias-directive* is not affected by the *using-alias-directive* itself or by other using-directives in the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. In other words, the *namespace-or-type-name* of a *using-alias-directive* is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using-directives

It provides simplified example of your exact problem, this is expected behavior:

```
namespace N1.N2 {}
namespace N3
{
   using R1 = N1;         // OK
   using R2 = N1.N2;      // OK
   using R3 = R1.N2;      // Error, R1 unknown
}
```

Comment: @Michael: We want to ensure that you are able to arbitrarily re-order using directives without introducing semantic changes in the program.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks as always, I was hoping you'd find and answer this - I was wondering as well.

Comment: This question was recently linked as a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366303/how-to-use-an-alias-type-as-a-generic-type-parameter-in-c-sharp) which is why I became aware of this answer. I noticed a loophole in the documentation and just wanted to bring this to yours, and others, attention. If you declare the `R1` alias in an outer namespace, the code compiles just fine. It's just when they're in the same namespace the block you cited from the specification blocks it. So move `using R1 = N1` out one level and `R3` compiles as well.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) says:

> The right side of a using alias
>   directive must always be a
>   fully-qualified type regardless of the
>   using directives that come before it.

So basically alias directives ignore other using directives.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question doesn't ask for a solution to eliminate the compile error while [This duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45366303/1941881) is asking about, I will list what I have found so far.

- Solution0: independent namespace ([Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429871/1941881))
- Solution1: nested namespace (inspired by [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429871/1941881))

  ```
  using StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
  namespace Inner {
      using ListOfStringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<StringList>;
      ...
  }
  ```
- Solution2: inheritance ([Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366358/1941881))

  ```
  using StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
  public class ListOfStringList : System.Collections.Generic.List<StringList> {}
  ...
  ```

But there will be some problems with Solution2 that you may have to wrap all constructors of the `System.Collections.Generic.List<StringList>`.