# Can a type alias refer to another type alias?

Tags: c#

When doing this in C#:

```
using Word = System.String;
using Words = System.Collections.Generic.List<Word>;
```

The compiler complains that "the type or namespace 'Word' could not be found". Is this not possible? If it makes a difference, I'm trying to do this in the global namespace.

EDIT: just found another SO that answers this: [Why can one aliased C# Type not be accessed by another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429829/why-can-one-aliased-c-sharp-type-not-be-accessed-by-another) This can marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. These aliases only apply within the namespace body.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can work around this limitation by moving the 2nd `using` inside the namespace body like this:

```
using Word = System.String;

namespace MyNamespace {
   using Words = System.Collections.Generic.List<Word>;
   ...
}
```

Comment: So, is there a solution to this? Moving these aliases within a named namespace makes no difference.

Comment: That's an interesting nugget of info that, FWICT, is not in the duplicated SO answer. Green check for you!

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is:

```
using Word = System.String;
using Words = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>;
```