# How to use an alias type as a generic type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, alias, using-directives

How do you pass an alias type defined by `using` to the generic class?

I tried the following code:

```
using ID = Int32; // it might be replaced with `String`.
using CC = C<ID>;

public class C<T> {
    T id;
}
```

and there will be an error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ID' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But the using directive is right above the line where the error occurs.
Did I miss something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This does not seem to be possible at the moment, plase see the first comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3720222/303290)

Comment: While the linked duplicate cites the specification, there is a way around it, declare `ID` in the outer namespace and `CC` in an inner namespace. The fact that they're in the same namespace is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know what you are trying to achieve with this, but you can, however, do something similar with inheritance

```
public class CC : C<ID>
{
}
```

The class `CC` will derive from `C<T>` with a concrete type. Hence `CC.T` will be of type `Int32` (or whatever).

Answer (score -1):

Don't use an alias.

```
public class C<T> {
   T id;
}
```

...

```
void Foo() {
  var x = new C<Int32>();

  var y = new C<string>();
}
```